# Replacing 1880s basement windows

Tags: windows

I have a home built in the 1880s.

Trying to get it ready for winter my problem is three windows that are rotting out in the basement walls.  This is a field stone and rubble foundation with old dry mortar surrounding the casements.

My question is what would be the most inexpensive way to go?  I'm a totally disabled war veteran and this also has to be something I can attempt to do as money for the windows and the labor I am sure are beyond my reach.

Comment: Pictures that show the details of the existing windows would be real helpful. It would allow us to see if the originals are salvageable. They may not salvageable. If they are, it will most likely not be cheaper to repair at all, at least in cost compared to replacing with new.

Answer (score 1):

If the framing around the window is essentially intact, insert replacement windows are fairly cheap and fairly easy, though you'll lose some glass area.. If the framing is rotting you'll need to deal with that; in that case either inserts or completely new framed windows may be the right choice. For the latter, make sure you install them with proper flashing & water barriers.

If you can't afford to replace the windows, all you can do is try to patch things well enough to not leak too badly and not fall apart. I have one basement window that I have temporarily just slapped a sheet of plexiglass across, held in place with caulking.... temporary ugly kluge but it does seal the opening better.

Answer (score 1):

I had a series of basement windows that were in very bad shape with rotted and broken frames. In addition the old original metal frames that were mortared to the basement walls were totally rusting away to nothing.

I ripped out the old windows and frames and cut away the metal inserts. I then had to chisel out the old mortar back to clean wall surfaces. After that I installed hollow glass window blocks using fresh mortar. Additional mortar was used to create a beveled fit of the opening edges up to the glass blocks. I used off the shelf vinyl vent screen assemblies in place of three of the glass blocks in the top center of the installation to allow for opening and venting of the new window.

I have to say that in the long run I was very pleased with the results of this replacement. On the inside once it became time to finish out the basement I made my own pine board trimming and window sills to fit up to the glass blocks and make everything look nice.

The cost of doing this as a DIY project was fairly reasonable. It may not be for everyone however due to the need to work with mortar and exercise glass block laying skills. I did spend a good amount of time honing the skill of setting the glass blocks and the vinyl vents. I do recall (15 years ago) that in the midst of doing two of the windows a surprise snow storm with freezing weather came on just as I had finished cementing in the blocks and applying beveled mortar edging on the outside. I had to quickly fashion some protective shrouds from corrugated cardboard and install heat lamps to keep the fresh mortar from freezing.

Comment: That's definitely the right approach. I'm still tempted to do it the wrong way and just shove insert windows into the existing metal frames, which aren't in awful shape.  There would be a bit more heat loss than a full replacement, but less than keeping the old metal single-panes currently there... and it avoids the battle of trying to pry or cut lose frames that were cast into the concrete when the foundation was poured.